# How do I return from a screen in Ren'Py?

Tags: python, return, renpy

My friends have decided to torture me with Ren'Py and I need help with this code for a visual novel.

```py
screen CorpseText():
    frame:
        xalign 0.5
        yalign 0.5
        text "barn är jobbiga"
        call label Return
        
        

screen Lik():
    imagebutton:
        xalign 0.5
        yalign 0.5
        idle "bg williamdedlolclose"
        action Show("CorpseText")
    
       


label start:

    scene bg williamdedlol

    "click on the body"
    call screen Lik 
    label Return:
    

    
    "(His back has been broken from the fall and like Manea said, it looks like he’s been stabbed in the face.)"
```

So what is supposed to happen is you go to the screen called "Lik" which shows a picture of a dead character and you are supposed to click on him. Then that is supposed to send you to Corpsetext and then I want to return to the dialog.

I have gotten tips from a lot of people. I have tried writing Return after Corpsetext and when that didn't work I wrote it before the dialog. Can someone help me change the code so it works?